# ignore more tag for a single category

Tags: php, wordpress

im using the more tag in the posts to display my content.
im trying to get wordpress to ignore the more tag for a single cateory

adding this code to the category.php (twenty-fourteen)
ignores the more tag only for the first post in the category

```
<?php 
if(is_category('top10')){
global $more; $more = -1;
$wp_query->query('showposts=10' . '&paged='.$paged);
}
?>
```

how can i make this happen for all the posts listed?

thanks in advance!